# Using double variables to create random number and cuttoffs

Tags: java, variables, random, output

I am having trouble with an assignment. I have to declare and initialize 9 double variables to 0.0. This means

```
    double A1 = 0.0;
    double A2 = 0.0;
    double A3 = 0.0;
    double A4 = 0.0;
    double A5 = 0.0;
    double A6 = 0.0;
    double A7 = 0.0;
    double A8 = 0.0;
    double A9 = 0.0;
```

right?

After that, it says with these 9 variables, make up a random number using a random number generator. With that new random number, I have to:

gather the random number cutoff at the 3rd decimal

gather the random number rounded at the 3rd decimal

gather the random number cutoff at the 4th decimal

gather the random number rounded at the 4th decimal

gather the random number cutoff at the 5th decimal

gather the random number rounded at the 5th decimal

gather the random number cutoff at the 6th decimal

gather the random number rounded at the 6th decimal.

Can someone explain to me how to make up a random number using those 9 variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever language you're using (which you should add to the tags) will have a random number generator in it. You'll need to use that. Additionally cutting off the decimal will probably require conversion to an integer.

Hopefully that leads you to the right answer without actually doing your homework for you :)